# VBA: Identify row where arguments x,y and z are true

Tags: vba, excel

my worksheet looks like:

```
  A        B             c
1 Name     Surname       Weight
2 Pete     Smith         91
3 Pete     Johnson       81
```

My Userform contains textboxes where one can fill in Name, Surname etc.

I'm looking for something like:

```
RowNumber = (textbox_Name == (A:A) ) & (textbox_Surname == Range(B:B) )
```

It's not easy to explain but I hope that you get the idea.

I know how to search in one column but does this work also in two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Absinthe posted, a `For` Loop is perfectly acceptable +1.  If you have lots of rows and find the loop to be slow you might consider using the `Match` function evaluating on multiple criteria instead.

```
Sub findMatchedRow()
    Dim matchedRow, wks, Criteria1, Criteria2

    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Criteria1 = wks.Cells(2, 7).Address(False, False)
    Criteria2 = wks.Cells(3, 7).Address(False, False)

    matchedRow = wks.Evaluate("MATCH(" & Criteria1 & "&" & Criteria2 & ",A2:A5&B2:B5,0)")

    If Not IsError(matchedRow) Then
        wks.Range("G6") = matchedRow
    Else
        wks.Range("G6") = "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

---

[image]

---

Note that the row number is based on the range and since the header row was not included it shows row 2 instead of actual row 3.  You can account for that or just include the header row if it's really on row 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop to go down the sheet and check each cell for your required values, something like:

```
Dim lastRow as long
Dim sName, surname, weight as string

sName = MyForm.MyControl.text ' etc etc - pick up the other form controls and put them to variables too

lastRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 to lastRow

     If cells(x, 1) = sName And cells(x,2) = surname And cells(x,3) = weight Then
         ' you've found a match
     End if

Next x
```

This uses the Cells propery of the Range class, the syntax is Cells(row, column) so cell A1 = Cells(1,1), cell C10 = Cells(10, 3) and so on. The for loop increments X at each iteration and thus moves to the next row.